# Multiple installation of netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Since we can install netbeans either using package manager or by using installer in netbeans website, I have these doubts.

1. What will happen if both the above options are used?
2. If the 2nd method is used, is there any problem with the ide for finding jdk installed         using package manager?
3. What are the problems if I update using 'Check for updates' option or install plugins from the ide installed using package manager? Is it requires root privilege for doing the above operations?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should get two launchers for each Netbeans installation. If you install each one system-wide, if they are installed in the same location, you may overwrite the package manager one or make `apt-get` complain when installing/removing the package manager one.
2. No, it should detect all the JDK's you have installed. If it fails then you can always locate them manually.
3. I haven't tried, but it should let you install them without root privileges. I remember some time ago Eclipse had a similar problem (permission/dependency problems when installing extensions).